# Can Boolean.valueOf(String) return null?

Tags: java, boolean

Can `Boolean.valueOf(String)` ever return null? From what I can see in the java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), the docs only specify when it returns true. Is false always returned otherwise, or can null be returned? I have not been able to get it to return null in the tests I have done, but I would like to be sure.

Essentially, I want to know if the following code is safe from a NullPointerException:

```
boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(...);
```

Comment: why don't you look the source . it just one line. posting question in this forum would take more time than look at source :)

Comment: Didn't realize the source was available. Will next time though thanks.

Comment: Note that the source may vary. There are many JVMs out there.

Comment: Note that "can it return `null`" and "can it throw an NPE" are NOT the same question.  And ... they do have different answers.  Respectively: 1) No, and 2) in some circumstances Yes!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The docs pretty much answer it: no. It'll return a `Boolean` representing a true or false.

The [code is also available](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Boolean.java#Boolean.valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: So if it cannot return null...Why return an object reference `Boolean` rather than the primitive type `boolean`? Just curious what the reasoning is.

Comment: The Javadocs don't specify when it was introduced, but I would guess it predates Java 1.5, in which autoboxing was introduced. So, if you had a `boolean` and needed a `Boolean` (for whatever reason), you would have needed to manually invoke `Boolean.valueOf(booleanPrimitive)`. The whole thing would have been `Boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(Boolean.valueOf(myString))`. I guess they thought that was a common-enough use case that they wanted to shorten it. But that's all speculation.

Comment: And on the flip side, if you need the primitive (without autoboxing), it's just `Boolean.valueOf(myString).booleanValue()`, which doesn't have nesting and is thus easier to read. So basically, either way they weren't going to hit all the use cases, so they picked one of them -- either because they thought it was more common, or because they thought it's more versatile (in that it converts to the other easier), or for some other reason.

Comment: Had to think twice about this answer. The spec says '(...) return a Boolean *with a value* (...)'. That implicitly excludes a null being returned, but I think the wording isn't clear enough

Comment: @orique `null` is not a `Boolean`; `null instanceof Boolean` will return `false`. See [JLS 4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1): `There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null`.

Comment: But you could return null from a method that returns Boolean

Comment: @orique I just edited my above comment to link to JLS 4.1, which defines the `null` type. The reason you can return `null` from any method that returns a reference type (like `Boolean`) is also in that section: `The null reference can always be assigned or cast to any reference type.` Basically, you're returning a `null` value that's casted to a `Boolean` reference, but you're not returning a `Boolean` value.

Comment: That said, I agree it's a distinction that's pretty subtly exploited in the javadoc wording. It's actually for the opposite reason than you initially quoted: it excludes `null` not because that's not a value (it is a value), but because it's not a `Boolean`.

Comment: Agree with that. I meant that the wording _of the spec_ wasn't clear enough to me.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is impossible. See the source code of the class `Boolean`:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

.. and then:

```
private static boolean toBoolean(String name) {
   return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it could cause NPE but can not return null. Try this:

```
Boolean bNull = null;
System.print(Boolean.valueOf(bNull)); // -> NPE!
```

This happens cuz `Boolean.valueOf()` accepts `String` or `boolean` values. Since `bNull` is of type `Boolean` java tries to unbox `bNull` value to pass it as `boolean` which causes NPE. Its funny but stupid actually... Also there is no `Boolean.valueOf()` for `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not. If null is placed within the argument or if  a string is set to null it will return a boolean value of false. You can see expected inputs and outputs in the Java docs: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#booleanValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#booleanValue%28%29)